# PHP Convert Nested Array Format

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following array with 2 elements:

```
$attribute_metric = array(2) 
{
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "white"
    [1]=>
    string(6) " Black"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "S"
    [1]=>
    string(2) " L"
    [2]=>
    string(2) " M"
  }
}
```

and I want to concatenate its elements in a way where I get one array that has 6 elements in which every element should look like this

```
[option_value] => Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [value] => white
  )

  [1] => Array(
    [value] => S
  )
)
```

I have tried the following but I still can't get close to what I want to achieve:

```
$final_attribute_metric = array();
        foreach ($attribute_metric[0] as $first_attribute) {
            foreach ($attribute_metric[1] as $second_attribute) {
                $final_attribute_metric[] = [$first_attribute,$second_attribute];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to come up with... but if you're trying to concat every array-of-size to each array-of-color.. then you can do the following...

```
$new = [];
foreach( $attribute_metric[0] as $colors ) {

  foreach( $attribute_metric[1] as $size ) {
     array_push( [ ['value'=>$color],['value'=>$size] ] );     
  }

}
```

The result should be ...

```
SixElementsArr = [

  0 => [
         0 => ['value'=>'white']
         1 => ['value'=>'S']
       ]
...//so on
]
```

Comment: actually what i want to achieve is an array of 6 elements(represents the combination of the array(white, black) with (S, L, M)) wherebey each element  contains the "option_value" array as shown in the question(the example shows the values 'white' and 'S', but i need an array that contains all the combinations)

Comment: Thank you victor.. that's what i wanted